# sending list of validation failed messaged to client?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, xsd, jax-ws

I am using `jax-ws` to develop soap based web-services. I have below end point and it has one web method as below.

```
@WebService
public interface MySoapService {

    @WebMethod
    public List<Result> getResult(TestRequest request);
}
```

Here TestRequest is generated from xsd using jaxb. I want to validate request against xsd.

Here if validation is failed then **i need to keep all validation errors in a list and send to client**. How can i do that? Please help me.

Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option A: Performance wise not the best solution, nor it wouldn't be the most elegant solution, but since you need a list all the errors - implementing ValidationEventHandler, handling schema validation in JAX-WS logical handler and throwing SOAP fault, seams to be the most appropriate solution.
Option B: In case using logical handler isn't attractive solution, SOAP payload might be be handled in SIB:

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

@WebMethod
public void test(String test) throws ValidationException {
    MessageContext messageContext = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    DOMSource source = (DOMSource) messageContext.getRequest().getPayloadSource();
    ...//Unmarshling and validating SOAP payload. Same as described in option A
}
```

Option C: Operating at lower level with added benefit that SOAP message would be unmarshaled once:

```
@WebServiceProvider
@ServiceMode(value=Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
public class TestProvider implements Provider<SOAPMessage>
{
    public SOAPMessage invoke(SOAPMessage request) 
    {
        SOAPBody requestBody = request.getSOAPBody();
        Document document = requestBody.extractContentAsDocument();
        ...//Unmarshling and validating SOAP payload. Same as described in option A
    }
}
```

Validation and other irrelevant stuff are described [here](http://javaeenotes.blogspot.com/2011/02/when-schemavalidation-in-jax-ws-web.html) and there's great [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/runtime006.htm) regarding schema validation.